# How to get a specific row and column from a DataFrame in Azure Databricks Spark

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a DataFrame in Azure Databricks which looks like

```
Col a| Col b
------------
Marc | Taylor
John | McC
Bill | Gates
```

I would like to extract a specfic column and row. I know how to extract a specific column and assign it to a variable

```
result = ds.select(Col a)
```

But how to get row number 2 for example in this line of code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `monotonically_increasing_id()` function to generate a new column with serial number and then use `filter` function to filter in the row

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
ds.withColumn('sn', monotonically_increasing_id())\
    .filter(col('sn') == 1)\
    .drop('sn')\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

which would give you

```
+-----+-----+
|Col a|Col b|
+-----+-----+
|John |McC  |
+-----+-----+
```

**Note: monotonically_increasing_id will generate increasing order numbers but not guaranteed to generate serial numbers starting from 0.**

To sum up, `filter()` and `select()/where()` functions are two ways to select rows from a dataframe

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

I can get the value with python using this:

`df_sample = yourDataFrame.select(collect_list("Col b").alias("a"))
value = df_sample.select(col("a").getItem(1).alias("x"))
display(value)`

hope it helps.